# dial error : 'too many open files'

Tags: sockets, tcp, go, network-programming

I am trying to write TCP client-server program, to find the maximum number of concurrent connection handled by server. So I create a simple server and initiated multiple tcp connection (using go routine).

server.go

```
func main() {
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":9100")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    defer ln.Close()
    fmt.Println("server has started")

    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
        conn.Close()
        fmt.Println("received one connection")
    }

}
```

client.go

```
func connect(address string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", address)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(-1)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    fmt.Println("connection is established")
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        fmt.Printf("connection %d", i)
        fmt.Println()
        go connect(":9100", &wg)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Print("all the connection served")
}
```

I was expecting that server will become unresponsive because of TCP SYN attach but my client application got crashed after ~2000 connection request. Following is the error message :

```
dial tcp :9100: too many open files
exit status 255
```

I need help for the following questions :

- What are the required changes in `client.go` to emulate the TCP connection flooding on my go server.
- How could I increase the number of open FD (mac OS), if there is limitation of maximum open FD for a precess.
- What is the default TCP queue size for the Listen() (in C programming language, queue size is specified in the `listen(fd, queue_size)`).

Edit :

- I found some help (question #2) for [increasing the number of open file descriptor](https://superuser.com/questions/302754/increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-file-descriptors-in-snow-leopard), but it is not working (no change in client error message).

ulimit settings

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 10000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Comment: what is your ulimit for open files (assuming POSIX here)?

Comment: I am using mac machine.

Comment: @JimB I have added some detail.

Comment: You're trying to create 10000 connections, and your ulimit is 10000, so there's no room for the other FDs the process will need. If fixing that that doesn't work, instead of exiting stop the program to see how many connections are open.

Comment: @JimB the error is completely random form FDs, sometime it happen at 1200 connection and sometime it reaches to 5000 connection. But it never reached to the 10000 connection.

Comment: You're reaching the limit on open file descriptors, there's nothing random here. Just because a connection isn't established, doesn't mean it hasn't consumed a file descriptor. Instead of trying to Dial 10000 connection simultaneously, create them serially while starting the clients.

Comment: Another gotcha; you are calling `defer conn.Close()` in the client. When there is an error creating the connection you're code immediately exists never reaching the `defer`. This leads to dangling connections and thus file descriptors. You can check if this is a problem with `lsof|grep client`.

Comment: @3of3 Right you are. I'm confusing this issue with an other I had some time ago in which the program kept running on an error.